Flutter Local Notification - Payload getting captured only in active state
I have a flutter app which is generating local notifications as per scheduled timing.
When the app is in active state/home page, and a notification is generated, I am able to capture the payload when the notification is clicked.
When the app is in inactive state, I am unable to do the same.
I have the following code in my main.dart.
Future<void> _initializeFlutterLocalNotifications() async {
  const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
  const InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid);

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
    initializationSettings,
    onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (NotificationResponse response) async {
      print('Notification clicked with payload: ${response.payload}');
      _handleNotificationClick(response.payload);
    },
  );
}


Flow of the app is Main -> Homepage with payload captured from the notification. or default.

for the background notifications you should add new parameter in

flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize

function and this function must be like this ;
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
    initializationSettings,
    onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {
        print('Notification clicked with payload: ${response.payload}'); 
        _handleNotificationClick(response.payload);   
    },
    onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: (NotificationResponse backgroundResponse) async {
        print('Background Notification Handled');
    },
);

Problem About Some Phone Models
Note that some Android OEMs has own Android OS that can prevent from running on the background. Some of Xaomi's and Huawei's models have this precaution. Consequently, local notification library can not work on these devices. If this is the case, you can control the application settings. In application settings you can let application to run on background.

Hi, Thanks for the response.
Unfortunately, this still does not work. I am still unable to capture the notification payload.
